# Prevent game from capturing mouse

Tags: directx, accessibility, directinput, gamecontroller

I'm working on a program for accessible PC gaming for people with mobility limitations. It will be like an on screen keyboard, except it will be a game controller. The problem is that most games capture the mouse input, so the user won't be able to click on the buttons in my program. The way I was planning to structure it is to emulate a Xinput game controller, so the mouse wouldn't be used at all in the game. Another option is for the game to see a virtual mouse and keyboard which would be driven by my program. I've been searching for a long time, and there aren't many options I've found, and they all have limitations.

So my question is, is there a way to prevent a game from capturing all mouse input that will work for any game in Windows.

**I know this might seem like it should go in Game Development, and that's where I posted it first, but really it's a technical question about how to accomplish this with any program that captures the mouse.**

Comment: You can capture the mouse in your own code (and ignore it), and not let the game get the respective windows messages. Although I don't understand why this would be important.

Comment: @Aganju I don't really know anything about how to do that. Do you know where I can get more information specifically how to do that? It needs to work for any method the game might use to capture the mouse. Thanks.

Comment: For starters, google `WM_MOUSEMOVE`.